# How to avoid overriding a package object in Scala?

Tags: scala

Say I have a two-subproject build with subprojects named `highlevel` and `lowlevel`; subproject `highlevel` depends on subproject `lowlevel`.  Both subprojects contribute to the package `com.example.foo`:

In `highlevel/src/main/scala/com/example/foo/package.scala`:

```
package com.example

package object foo {
  def bar = ???
}
```

In `lowlevel/src/main/scala/com/example/foo/package.scala`:

```
package com.example

package object foo {
  def wee = ???
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I use `com.example.foo` in the `highlevel` project, `wee` is no longer defined because `lowlevel`'s `com.example.foo` package object is being "overshadowed" by that of `highlevel`.  Is there any way of having both `bar` and `wee` coexist in subproject `highlevel`?

(For those interested, the use case is when `bar` and `wee` are implicit conversions: `bar` would handle a conversion involving a type defined in `highlevel`, while `wee` would handle a conversion involving a type defined in `lowlevel`.  Both subprojects need the low-level type conversion `wee`.)

Answer (score 2):

A `package object` is an `object`; it is not a `package`. You can't define a package object twice for the same reason that the following code is invalid:

```
object A
object A
```

What you can do is rename `lowlevel/src/main/scala/com/example/foo/package.scala` to `lowlevel/src/main/scala/com/example/foo/LowLevel.scala`, and change it from a `package object` to a `trait`.

Then the high-level package object can inherit it:

```
package com.example
package object foo extends com.example.foo.LowLevel
```

It's fairly common to define things in traits so that package objects can be composed this way. Scalaz does it extensively.

Comment: Yes, shortly after posting this question I came across [SI-4964](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4964), so it's intentional behavior, and for exactly the reason you said.

Comment: Looking into the Scalaz source for examples, I could only find one package object that does this in the `series/8.0.x` branch and two in the `series/7.3.x` branch.  Am I missing something?

Comment: This solution seems to work only if the high-level package object does extend `com.example.foo.LowLevel`.  If it doesn't, the low-level code will throw a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` during runtime when calling code that is defined in `LowLevel`.

Comment: @DanielLi Sorrym, my recollection was wrong - scalaz doesn't group traits into package objects - but it does group traits into objects (e.g. the main object [`scalaz.Scalaz`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Scalaz.scala)), which is just the same thing with a different naming convention.

Comment: @DanielLi You'll have to change all of the low-level code's references. Things that were referring to the package object will now have to use the `LowLevel` object, since that's where they're been moved to.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is at least one difference between package objects and regular objects: the compiler will complain if two objects from different projects share the same name in the same package, but it will happily compile when those two objects are package objects (which then potentially leads to the `NoSuchMethodError`).

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify? I must be missing something: if I change all the low-level code's references to use the `LowLevel` object*, that would defeat the purpose of having conveniently available definitions in a package object.

(*Also, did you mean trait, not object?)

Comment: A package object or a non-package object, why does it make a difference? (I mean object, assuming that the companion object to the `LowLevel` trait will be defined as `object LowLevel extends LowLevel`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108134/discussion-between-daniel-li-and-chris-martin).